# Squid asks for username and password when using NTLM

Tags: ntlm, squid

I have a proxy running squid and dansguardian on Ubuntu 9.10 server. It is joined to active directory and login succeeds. I've setup squid and dansguardian to use ntlm and it seems working. When I try to connect, it asks for password and when I provide my domain username and password, I can start browsing.

However, it may be annoying for some people when they start to use this proxy. Is it possible to not ask username and password at least on IE?

Proxy has currently 172.16.X.X ip on local net

Regards,
Burak

Comment: probably more to serverfault =)

Answer (score 1):

It's all about winbindd_privileged. I've added squid into winbindd_priv group and it worked.